# Quick Jquery question regarding skipping parents of elements and addClasses to childs

Tags: jquery

I have a quick problem that I need solved and other than writing the JQuery, I think it would be simpler if I explained it in a very basic way. Starting with the class "todays", how can I add the class "red" to the next 3 elements after todays class and bypass the parent? When I use next() function, it stops at the end of the td . Any help would be appreciated!

Jquery - I know how to add one to the next element, but not to the next 3

```
$('tr td.today').next().addClass('red');
```

HTML

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td class="today">2</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>4</td>
 <td>5</td>
 <td>6</td>
</tr>
```

So if I want to add "red" to the next 3 td elements after todays class, it would look like this.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td class="todays">2</td>
  <td class="red">3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="red">4</td>
  <td class="red">5</td>
  <td>6</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. One would be to use the index of the `.today` element along with `slice()` to select the correct elements.

```js
var $td = $('td'); // Collection of all TDs
var todayIndex = $td.index($('.today')); // The index of .today within the collection

$td = $td.slice(todayIndex + 1, todayIndex + 4); // New collection containing the next three TDs

$td.addClass('red');
```

```css
.today {
  color: green;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
    <td>-3</td>
    <td>-2</td>
    <td>-1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="today">2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I was playing around with the slice but I couldn't figure out how to establish the index for today class. I cannot thank you enough!!